# UICollectionView all sections are not displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using `UICollectionView` and using [RFQuiltLayout](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=rfquiltlayout) library. I am dynamically assigning the `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` and `numberOfItemsInSection`. Right now 17 sections are getting assigned to the collection View. But while displaying it is displaying only one section.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"tableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 UILabel* label = (id)[cell viewWithTag:21];
    if(!label) label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 0, cell.frame.size.width-4, cell.frame.size.height)];

    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    label.tag=21;
    label.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.numberOfLines = 2;
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:11]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
     NSLog(@"total section assigned %ld",(long)collectionView.numberOfSections);
    NSLog(@"current section %ld",(long)indexPath.section);
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
       if (indexPath.row == 0) {
           label.text = @"Category";
           [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:11]];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:127/255.f green:151/255.f blue:201/255.f alpha:1];
        }else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            label.text = @"Current";
            [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:11]];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.f green:176/255.f blue:142/255.f alpha:1];
        }
   }else {
        CrimeAnalysisTable *aTable = [self.tableDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section - 1];

        if (indexPath.row  == 0) {
            label.text = aTable.category;
   }
    }
    [cell setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
}
[cell setNeedsLayout];

return cell;
}
```

I am using the above code to Display the section but the code is not going in the else part

the `NSLog` for number of section is printing `17` and for current section is printing `0`. But the count is not going beyond `0` .

Comment: you set only first section first row value like this condition `if (indexPath.section == 0) {` so how can display other section value? @Shriti

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya but i have implemented else part. If section is not 0 it should go in else but it is not going. Current section count is 0 only. And the assigned sections are 17